# CSS - Make card box bigger, than it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got piece of Javascript and CSS.

Javascript:

```
$('.item-card').css("width", $('.item-card').width() + "px");
$('.item-card').css("font-size", $('.item-card').width() * .13 + "px");
```

CSS:

```
  margin-left: 1vw;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  right: -15%;
  width: 10vw;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: normal;
```

Okay, with that CSS, it's "perfect" box for item showing, but my problem is I would like it to be bigger, but If I change that width.. nothing happens. How could I make that box bigger?

Comment: Have you tried  width:10vw !important; ?

Comment: need a working example... you're setting width using jquery in px, and in css in vw...

Comment: Hmm, seems like that "box" still is 131px x 181px

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The code that you're using right now converts the width from units "vw" to units "px", but doesn't actually change the on-screen width.

If you want the box to change size, you'll need to do some sort of operation with your call to the width property before setting it again:

```
// double the width
$('.item-card').css("width", $('.item-card').width() * 2 + "px");
```

Make sure you also modify the 'height' property if you want the box to keep the same dimensional ratio.

Comment: on css, there is no "heigh" property, but okay. I will test/check and report back :)

Comment: Finally it came up, I look at Chrome Inspect element. I see http://prntscr.com/ardd20, but on CSS I got

Comment: `      width: 15px;
   height: 20px;`

Comment: Hi Richard, height is definitely a CSS property, and can be accessed in JQuery the same way you accessed the width property: `$('.item-card').height()`

Comment: @richard Ras: You're setting width based on viewport width (of your browser window). Then apparently you use javascript (jquery actually) to get that width and convert it to a px size. The outcome will depend on your browser width... if your js is even working. Why not go back and read the recommendation of Paulie_D

Comment: I don't get width with jQuery? That part is ONLY what "does" that process